# Websockets with the python web framework "quart"?

Tags: python, flask, python-asyncio, quart

I need help with the python web frame work, [Quart](https://github.com/pgjones/quart), more specifically the websockets.  I would like to be able to register a client when it connects (add it to a python list), and unregister them (remove it from the python list) when it disconnects.  The closest thing I could find on the web is this code:

```
connected = set()

async def handler(websocket, path):
    global connected
    # Register.
    connected.add(websocket)
    try:
        # Implement logic here.
        await asyncio.wait([ws.send("Hello!") for ws in connected])
        await asyncio.sleep(10)
    finally:
        # Unregister.
        connected.remove(websocket)
```

[source](http://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html)

But this does not work with quart websockets.

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This decorator when used to wrap a websocket handler, will add and remove websockets from the `connected` set. The `_get_current_object` method of the websocket is required to get the websocket in the current [context](https://pgjones.gitlab.io/quart/contexts.html), and the try-finally is required to ensure the websocket is removed regardless of any errors that are raised. Note the `app.websocket` must wrap (be before) the `collect_websocket` usage.

```
from functools import wraps

connected = set()

def collect_websocket(func):
    @wraps(func)
    async def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        global connected
        connected.add(websocket._get_current_object())
        try:
            return await func(*args, **kwargs)
        finally:
            connected.remove(websocket._get_current_object())
    return wrapper                                                                                                                                                                                                            


@app.websocket('/ws')                                                                                                                                                                                       
@collect_websocket
async def ws():
    ...
```

Edit:
I am the Quart author.

Comment: I get this error:

    line 20, in collect_websocket
         @wraps(func)
    NameError: name 'wraps' is not defined,

Is there something im missing?

Comment: `from functools import wraps` probably, [see docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps)