# Python error when attempting to run on heroku

Tags: python, heroku, flask, web-deployment

Im trying to deploy a python app to heroku. I use a web framework called quart (an asyncio adaptation of flask). The build succeeds when I try to deploy, but in the heroku logs, I get this error message:

```
TypeError: __call__() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were
```

This is the code that runs the app:

```
if __name__ == '__main__': 
     app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=int(os.environ['PORT']))
```

My procfile consists of this:

```
web: gunicorn main_loop:app
```

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you're missing a few closing brackets on the app.run call.

Comment: @ktzr, Oh sorry, that was just a mistake in the copy and pasting...

Comment: @DupDup Do you still get the error, or did that fix it?

Comment: @pushkin I still get the error ( I didn't copy the full line of code when is was making this post).

Answer (score 1):

Quart requires a specific Gunicorn worker class[1](https://pgjones.gitlab.io/quart/deployment.html). I think if your procfile was

```
web: gunicorn --worker-class quart.worker.GunicornWorker main_loop:app
```

it would work. (I don't have a heroku dyno available to test though).

(I am the Quart author)

Comment: It works for serving the web-page, but I get this javascript error concerning the websocket: 

`Mixed Content: The page at 'https://dertio.herokuapp.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but attempted to connect to the insecure WebSocket endpoint 'ws://dertio.herokuapp.com/ws'. This request has been blocked; this endpoint must be available over WSS.
(anonymous) @ (index):266`

Comment: If I set my browser to connect to the websocket (the websocket connection was blocked for being unsafe) , the app works, but the performance is unbelievably slow, any fix for this?

Comment: Sorry, but there isn't enough information for me to answer either of those questions - nor really for me to take a guess.

Comment: The websocket runs as you explained in my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49837294/websockets-with-the-python-web-framework-quart), but I don't have a clue whats causing the slowness (It runs fast on localhost).

Comment: As it turns out, I can fix the websockets by having my URL as http instead of https. I still don't know why its so slow though.

Comment: can i replace all that with ‘hypercorn app:app’?

Comment: Almost, given the example it would be `hypercorn main_loop:app`